# How do you view only files shared with you for a certain project In Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, sharing

I'm working on a particular project with two other people and whenever I go to "shared with me" it shows everything that was ever shared with me, which is quite a lot. Only individuals have been shared with me for the current project, so they're not in one folder. Is there a way I can at least filter by author (or any better idea)?

Answer (score 2):

If you star the items in the *Shared with Me* folder, then these items will appear in your *Starred* folder.

This will only help for one project though.

Comment: Is it possible for me to create a new folder specifically for the project, then drag and drop all the shared files into it? Or would this screw it up for the other users?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is when I originally create the files, I put them all in one folder and then share the whole folder with collaborators. You can also add shared files to "Your Drive" (so that they show up in your main screen) and put them in a folder there; that won't screw it up for other users.

To add a shared file to your drive, select the file (in the shared with me screen) and look for this button;

[image: Add to my Drive]

This is a problem I had a lot too; hope this helps!

evamvid